# What meta tags are used in HTML in order for media queries to work?

Tags: media-queries

I am trying to create some media queries in my Css but it isnt registering. I did not use any approximate meta tags. What meta tags do I need to use in order to get my media queries to register?

Comment: it's called viewport tag https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: THANK YOU! I just found that on another site

Answer (score 0):

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 480px) {

 }
```

OR

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 480px)" href="mystylesheet.css">
```

You need to add meta tag viewport:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
```